# Writing my custom bug repository mylyn connector, where should I start?

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I want to write a mylyn connector for the bug repository my team uses, I was able to set the workspace and activate a couple of small things by using the web resources and Bugzilla and Trac code.

But I am lost, is there is good tutorial for this issue?
Maybe a simpler connector for examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you check out Mylyn Connector Crash Course slides available at http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/developers/. It is an overview of Mylyn API with hands-on tutorial about building simple connector. Maybe you can also find the talk itself recorded somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/Integrator_Reference#Tasks_API?